# How to answer purpose of visit for a company meetup with tourism aftewards

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas

I am going for our company meetup to Germany. After that I plan to visit 3-4 days for tourism. How should I answer the immigration officer when they ask what the purpose of the visit is? I applied for a business visa earlier

My visa business letter stated that I will take part in a company meet for one week and the other 3-4 days would be team building or on site.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"My main purpose is to take part in a company meetup. I also plan to spend some extra days to explore the city."

This should be enough. Note that your main purpose is the company meetup, aka business. You should state like that when asked to pin point a purpose. It’s totally normal to spend some days after business visit in the city.

Comment: Isn't this a long answer generally I read people suggested to say only one sentence. so it could be like "Purpose is to take part in a company meetup"  WDYT?

Comment: @sahil That also works. But, if you are upfront about your plans, you will generally avoid subsequent questions.

Comment: I see I was asking because from the company side like I mentioned above so is all part of company boding activities it never started in the invitation/business letter that I will do something outside of the trip.

Comment: @sahil Oh! You are saying that its a company sponsored leisure event? Then no need to mention it separately.

Comment: @sahil This is not a particularly long answer. The take-away principle from advice saying "only one sentence" is that you should directly and succinctly answer their questions (which this answer does), in a way that will often consist of only 1 sentence, not that you should avoid 2 sentences at all cost.